# JSON Schema Semantic Versioning

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have a service that manages some system configurations, these configurations are stored in the filesystem as a .json file. On each boot, the service will start, read the configuration and use the values to modify said system configurations.

Before using the values, I'm using a JSON schema validator, to confirm that the data is okay.

Now my question is, how can I achieve semantic versioning for the JSON schema and check if the json data is using the correct version.

Currently if the schema changes and the data doesn't the validator exits with an error code, which is good. But what isn't great is the error message I'm receiving.

What I like to do is, check before validation if the version of the data matches the version of the schema, and if it doesn't, throw an expection that tells the user that the data is incompatible to the schema because of a version mismatch.

After doing some research I came across the following key in the JSON schema:

```
"$id": "https://my-company.org/schemas/config/0.1.0/config.schema.json"
```

This URI could be used for controlling the version of the schema itself, but how would i check if the data is using the correct version of that schema?

Comment: It would have to be defined somewhere in the data. I don't know what else you are expecting. Are you thinking there might be some way to determine it without it being specified?

Comment: @Relequestual yes, that was what i was hoping for .. So i basically have to include something in my schema as well as in my data that looks like this:

"schema": {
  "version": "0.1.0"
}

Comment: Yes. Although using the `$id` URI to indicate version is preferable. The ID is supposed to be unique and ideally not change.

Comment: @Relequestual so basically use the $id in the schema to specify the version in the URI and introduce a key in the data that hold information about the used version of the schema, is this correct? :)

Comment: Yup, exactly! That's how I'd do it.
You could even store the full URI in your data.
It's not official (not part of the JSON Schema specification), but some tools use a key of `$schema` in the data to infur the schema for the data. You'll find this in VSCode for example. The choice is yours =]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Storing the version identifier as part of the URI in `$id` is common, and seems to be the best solution for versioning JSON Schema. (I haven't seen a better solution, and it is proven that this approach works at scale.)

Alternativly, you could add your own field in JSON Schema, but people and code would need to know to look for it.

When you validate data with JSON Schema, you sometimes load in all your schemas, then specify the ID of the one you want to use.

Storing the schema version you want some JSON data to be validated against can be done however you like. While not defined in the JSON Schema specification, it's commonplace to store the full URI as defined in the schemas `$id` value to be inculded in the data in a `$schema` field.

It's not defined in the specification because we don't want to prescribe requirements on data.